# Shim between tripod plate and camera body for lanyard

Tags: tripod, camera-straps

I'd like to mount both a [Spider designs holster](https://spiderholster.com/spiderpro/) place and a [Peak Design Clutch](https://www.peakdesign.com/product/straps/clutch). I've managed to connect the clutch to the Spider base plate but it stops the baseplate functioning as a tripod plate. What I've worked out I need is a metal shim between the Spider plate and camera body with a couple of lanyard loops in it - does such a thing exist or am I going to have to go to the metal shop?

Comment: No experience w/ the Spider but, in looking at the pictures, it seems the baseplate has some holes with which one could loop the clutch connection. It would interfere at the bottom, but you could grind out a small groove for it to retreat into so that the plate can be flush with a tripod, no?

Comment: When you say "tripod plate", what do you mean? Are you saying that the tripod mounting threads are now being used, so you can't screw the camera onto a tripod?

Comment: @corey I thought that but the obvious holes are on the LHS of the baseplate. File/grinder is my final resort...

Comment: @scottbb the spider plate is an ARCA Swiss tripod plate with a second thread so I could add the peak plat too. It would be massively fugly though :-)

Comment: I guess I'm still unclear what you're trying to do. You linked to the SpiderPro, but then you say it's an Arca plate. But the SpiderPro plate is not Arca compatible (unless you have the add-on Arca plate meant for the SpiderPro.

Comment: Can you upload a picture of what you have rigged up so far?

Comment: This sounds like an x → y question. What is the reason you want to mount both devices to your camera at the same time? Perhaps there is a better solution to *that* problem?